# Regex is not working in Python Playwright page.wait_for_url()?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I found a strange difference in Python VS JavaScript regex implementation of `page.waitForURL()` / `page.wait_for_url()`.

In python version this code doesn't work:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page")
    page.wait_for_url(r"docs/api")
    browser.close()
```

In JavaScript version it works fine:

```js
// @ts-check
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  // Try to add 'playwright.firefox' to the list ↓
  for (const browserType of [playwright.chromium, playwright.webkit]) {
    const browser = await browserType.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page');
    await page.waitForURL(/docs\/api/);
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Comment: What exactly is it thats not working? Does it not wait for the url? Or does it error?

Comment: @OPSM in python version there is a timeout error in `page.wait_for_url()`, but it's expected code to work without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r""` strings are raw strings in Python, not regex strings. It so happens that many regex functions in the `re` library accept plain strings as arguments, which require escaping, so it's common to see `r""` strings in conjunction with regex. The purpose is to ensure all `\` characters are literal, so you can write `\b` rather than `\\b`.

Instead of using a compiled regex as described [in hardcoded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78028823/6243352), I'd suggest using the `**/docs/api` syntax, which works in both Python

```py
page.wait_for_url("**/docs/api/*")
```

and JS

```js
await page.waitForURL("**/docs/api/*");
```

To me, this reads easier (in Python, no `re.compile()` call and having to remember to add the `r` to `r""`, and in JS, no backslash escaping) and is less prone to unexpected regex characters creating false positives.

If you pass in a plain string (raw or otherwise) rather than a regex, Playwright assumes you're using this "glob" syntax, which is mostly a normal string with asterisks for skipping one or more path segments. `page.wait_for_url(r"docs/api")` is waiting for an exact match that never happens, hence the timeout.

Answer (score 4):

You need to compile the expression:

```
import re
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page")
    page.wait_for_url(re.compile(r"docs/api"))
    browser.close()
```